# How to Find formula from values x and Y

Tags: polynomials

How to find formula, based on this data: 
x=1, y=9 
x=3, y=6 
x=5, y=3 
x=7, y=0

If I put this data into the cartesian coordinate, the this graph is produced:
[image: Linear Polynomial]

How to calculate the formula for this graph?
Please explain to me in easy way. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: you only need two points in this case since it is a straight line. Let $y=mx+c$ and solve for m and c with any two points

Comment: By observation, $y$ decreases by $3$ each time $x$ increases by $2$. So you are looking for some formula like $\,y=-\frac{3}{2}\,x + c\,$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

A line has a cartesian equation of the form

$$y-y_0=\frac {\Delta y}{\Delta x}(x-x_0) $$

with $x_0=7\;,\;y_0=0,$$
$$\Delta x=3-2,\Delta y=6-9$, we find

> $$y=-\frac {3}{2}(x-7) $$

Comment: I think: delta x = 3-1